Do antibodies binding to the same epitope have similar electrophoretic mobility?
Serum protein electrophoresis is a commonly used blood test in medicine. It is often used for detection of paraproteins in the gamma-globulin region. If there is a narrow band with sharp borders present, this is interpreted as presence of a monoclonal antibody.
However, this is a large jump into conclusion. The presence of a narrow band with sharp borders simply tells us that there is an accumulation of antibodies with similar electrophoretic mobility. Of course, one possible cause of this accumulation is presence of large numbers of antibodies created by one clone as they will all have the same electrophoretic mobility. One of the possible causes for this is an accumulation of a single clone of abnormal B-cells which produce this single type of antibodies.
This is usually the only cause that is taken into regard when assessing for the cause of a narrow band in the gamma-globulin region, so the differential diagnosis consists of malignant and premalignant hematological disorders. However, there are also other possible causes for this electrophoretic pattern. In this article which evaluated the causes of presence of this narrow band in children, it was noticed that it can appear in a variety of diseases - immunodeficiencies, hematological malignancies, aplastic anemia, autoimmune diseases, infectious diseases and also some others. As this study was done in the pediatric population in which monoclonal gammopathy of undetermined significance is extremely rare, it is highly likely that these conditions were in fact the causes of the narrow band in the gamma-globulin region and that the patients did not have concomitant MGUS.
The authors explain the pathogenesis of the electrophoretic pattern in these conditions by refering to an article which attempted to to categorize the causes of monoclonal gammopathy. However, the author of this categorization also assumed that the narrow band is caused by a single B-cell clone proliferation and admitted that the pathogenesis of the presence of a narrow band in the gamma-globulin region in autoimmune diseases wasn't understood well enough.
Different autoimmune diseases have different pathways of mechanisms. The most common mechanism is the presence of a humoral response towards self-antigens. As different antibodies can bind to the same epitope, an autoimmune disease can cause massive overproduction of multiple different antibodies targeting the same self-antigen.
This is where my question is coming from. Do antibodies binding to the same epitope have similar electrophoretic mobility? If this is true, then the premise that a narrow band in the gamma-globulin region of serum electrophoresis is always caused by a single B-cell clone proliferation is wrong. Because that would mean that an overproduction of multiple different antibodies binding to the same epitope could also cause the narrow band. This could be an explanation of how some autoimmune diseases cause the narrow band.
